# How to implement Gremlin query corresponding to Neo4j cypher query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, gremlin, amazon-neptune, gremlinpython

I have the following Cypher query(neo4j) and want to convert it to a Gremlin query.

```
MATCH d=(a:Actor {id:" + entityId +'})-[r:ACTING_IN*0..2]-(m) WITH d, 
RELATIONSHIPS(d) AS rels WHERE NONE (rel in r WHERE rel.Type = "Hollywood") RETURN *
UNION
MATCH d=(aa:Actor{id: " + entityId + "})-[rel:PRODUCER_OF*0..2]->(mm:Movie) WITH d, 
RELATIONSHIPS(d) AS rels return *
```

Please help, Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, then you are trying to run 2 variable length patterns to get path and relationship traversed in those paths.
I think below query should do the trick:

```
g.V(" + entityId +").
  hasLabel("Actor").
  union(
    repeat(outE("ACTING_IN").hasNot('Type', "Hollywood").as('a').inV()).
      emit().
      times(2),
    repeat(outE("PRODUCER_OF").as('a').inV().hasLabel("Movie")).
      emit().
      times(2)).
  path().
  project("path", "relationship").by().by(select('a'), all)
```